# Serverless Multiplayer

Tags: android, architecture, multiplayer, mobile

I wanted to make a game with a "serverless" mobile multiplayer game.
The idea was to have devices connect to each other automatically when they are within range.
There would be no global game state but just the one created by the first one to start their game or be in one place. When others join the game state is forwarded to them and the themselves send it to devices that are connected to them.
This happens everytime there is a significant change.
The game itself would be kind of an rpg with a location based gameplay (mostly to have the players socialize)
The idea was to only have players who are close to each other play together.
Now: the actual question: How can I realize this idea? Things I found online were Android Wifi Direct or Bluetooth but both seem to have their problems for this project. Is there any way I can actually build my game?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Things I found online were Android Wifi Direct or Bluetooth but both seem to have their problems for this project.` What are these problems? What are you trying to build? I would suggest bluetooth but I don't know why it wouldn't work on your game, so from the options I can think, I don't know if it's worth suggesting anything. Also keep in mind `mmo` and connect to only local devices do not go together.

Comment: @TomTsagk so far I couldn't find any way to automatically connect to devices via bluetooth with no further user input.
If there were any I'd be glad to try them.

Comment: Add that information to your question, so people attempting to answer do not have to search through the comments. In most cases devices connecting directly with each other **need** some user input, for security reasons. I'm not sure how possible it is to connect multiple devices locally in a wireless way, without users being aware of it. I think though that its possible to connect two devices in such way with bluetooth, as long as both devices have your app open at the same time and bluetooth has been activated. Have you tried it at all?

Comment: @TomTsagk I've been doing research for 2 days now since it's my first time building something with a multiplayer and I couldn't find anything that was helpful. Everything was using a server or directly over the internet which would require me to have to IP address of every device I want to connect.

Comment: Did you search if you can achieve that with bluetooth? Last time I made something using bluetooth, it required the user to select which user to connect with, but I'm pretty sure it would be possible to automate that.